# Local phpMyAdmin to remote mySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, ssh-tunnel

I've a local dockerized phpMyadmin and a remote docker service running a mySQL container. The port 3306 is not exposed on the internet and I'm using a tunnel:

```
ssh -f user@remotedb -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

Using a raw mysql client I can connect to the sql service using: 127.0.0.1/user/password.
phpMyadmin is not able to reach it. This is its config:

```
pma:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  container_name: pma
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - 'PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=https://pma.local/'
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=pma.local
  volumes:
    - './config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php'
  restart: always
```

And the custom php file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = 'Remote Server';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';
$i++;
```

For reference I'm using this docker pma image: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker. What am I missing here? Do I need other port(s)? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/kingsquare/tunnel/)?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that on the container itself there's nothing listening on the port 3306. The port is anyway available on the host, so my quick-and-dirty solution would be to use the IP of the docker0 interface (usually `172.17.0.1`).

So in your custom pho file, you might want to use something like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '172.17.0.1';
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting your answer. The 127.0.0.1 is already working with sql client it's saying accept connection only from "localhost". How should I change that? Are you referencing docker0 interface on the mysql container?

Comment: You are actually right... the last part about the tunnel is simply wrong. Sorry. I fix the answer again